# function can return another function use in swift

Tags: swift

Functions are a first-class type. This means that a function can return another function as its value.

> ```
> func makeIncrementer() -> (Int -> Int) {
> func addOne(number: Int) -> Int {
>     return 1 + number
> }
> return addOne
> }
> var increment = makeIncrementer()
> increment(7)
> ```

when i implement this i got the following error:

> Command
>   /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   failed with exit code 254

Also where this functionality can be useful in realtime solutions?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Its working for me without any modification. error is something else

Comment: @Anil after using M M. answer i am able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Functions.html), your function declaration should be like below code, See the parentheses around `Int`. It indicates the entry parameters.

```
func makeIncrementer() -> (Int) -> Int
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This funcionality can make it easier to have dynamic code based on a value in run-time.